# Find text in Google Document and highlight it using Google Apps Script

Tags: web-applications, replace, google-apps

I would like to find a text (even all instances of that text) and highlight it using the script. I created the following function,but whenever I run the function is says 
**We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again.**

Any ideas on how to fix this? it would be appreciated, thank you.

```
function onOpen() {
var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();

ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
  .addItem('Search And Navigate', 'highlightText').addToUi();
}
function highlightText(target,background) {
// If no search parameter was provided, ask for one
if (arguments.length == 0) {
var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
var result = ui.prompt('Text Highlighter','Enter text to highlight:',   ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

// Exit if user hit Cancel.
if (result.getSelectedButton() !== ui.Button.OK) return;
// else

target = result.getResponseText();
}

var background = background || '#F3E2A9';
var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
var bodyElement = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
var searchResult = bodyElement.findText(target);

while (searchResult !== null) {
var thisElement = searchResult.getElement();
var thisElementText = thisElement.asText();

//Logger.log(url);
thisElementText.setBackgroundColor(searchResult.getStartOffset(), searchResult.getEndOffsetInclusive(),background);

// search for next match
searchResult = bodyElement.findText(target, searchResult);
}
}
```